# Visual studio code cannot edit files on samba shared folder

Tags: command-line, bash, permissions, samba, visual-studio-code

I got some problems with my samba service, when I mount shared folder from command line on Ubuntu using this:

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o user=$USER,uid=ubuntu-user,gid=ubuntu-user //ip-address/samba-folder /target
```

The folder mount ad i can read and write almost everything but files with only extension I cannot (ex. `.env`).

[image]

I can edit the first file but the others that are only `.*` I receive this error:

> Failed to save '.env': Command failed: cd "/home/tommaso"; "/usr/bin/pkexec" --disable-internal-agent /bin/bash -c "echo SUDOPROMPT; "/usr/share/code/bin/code" --file-write "/home/tommaso/.config/Code/code-elevated-WX8vT7b1" "/home/tommaso/Dietpi/home-server/cloudflare/.env"" Error using --file-write: EACCES: permission denied, open '/home/tommaso/Dietpi/home-server/cloudflare/.env'

In the other hand, if I mount the folder from Ubuntu 'Server connection' as below:

[image]

The mount allow me to edit every kind of file also the `.*` file, so I think that is related with something like permissions or `mount` CLI command.

P.S. I cannot exec `chmod` on mounted folder and the files inside the mounted folder are already owned by `ubuntu` user (also the group).

Ubuntu 23.04